# Postgres 9.3 workload consumes all of memory and swap

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a AWS instance running Postgres 9.3 with 4GB of memory and 2 vCPUs. There seems to be a tipping point where heavy load tests cause postmaster processes start consuming all of memory and eventually all of swap (1GB). I think the values in the postgresql.conf file look pretty conservative for that amount of memory.

I even have tried dropping shared_buffers to 2GB, max_connections to 20...no effect it just keeps eating memory and swap.

It should be noted that I've got 100 schemas. Can anyone spot something I am missing?

```
archive_command = 'cd .'
archive_mode = on
archive_timeout = 300
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
checkpoint_segments = 64
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
default_statistics_target = 100
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
effective_cache_size = 3GB
hot_standby = on
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_monetary = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_time = 'en_US.UTF-8'
listen_addresses = '*'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'
logging_collector = on
log_rotation_age = 1d
log_rotation_size = 0
log_timezone = 'UTC'
log_truncate_on_rotation = on
maintenance_work_mem = 256MB
max_connections = 80
max_wal_senders = 10
password_encryption = on
shared_buffers = 1GB
shared_preload_libraries = 'repmgr_funcs'
timezone = 'UTC'
track_activities = on
track_counts = on
track_io_timing = on
wal_buffers = 16MB
wal_keep_segments = 288
wal_level = 'hot_standby'
max_locks_per_transaction=256
work_mem = 4MB
```

Comment: 1. please detail what kind of "heavy load test" is used? how many concurrent sessions, what kind of workload? 2. did you try to remove repmgr and retest? 3. did you try with "vanilla" unmodified config?

Comment: 100 tenants (meaning hitting 100 different schemas) with 500 Virtual users (5 per tenant) attempting to get a total of 150 TPM.  Will try repmgr.  Yes tried vanilla no change.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following approach:

1. Ensure it is an issue. That is: drive the database to the "failure" condition, and take a snapshot of `top` output. You want to find a `postgresql` process that has maximal `RSS-SHR` value
2. Analyze memory consumption of the `postgresql` process in question. You can follow [PostgreSQL wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ#Examining_backend_memory_use) and/or https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/checking-per-memory-context-memory-consumption/
3. Take a nap
4. Identify the bug by a mere analysis of #2
5. In case #4 fails, post #1 and #2 to [pgsql-hackers](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/) mailing list